Setting up NVIDIA drivers on ubuntu gets rid of GUI
I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. On HP ZBook Power 16 inch G11 Mobile Workstation PC. It contains Nvidia RTX 2000 Ada Generation Laptop GPU. I am having trouble installing its driver. I downloaded driver version 550.90.07. Below are all supported versions for this GPU (link):

I first installed gcc-13 and then executed the downloaded driver file NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-550.90.07.run. It executed successfully and showed the GPU information when I run nvidia-smi command. But when I restarted the PC, it showed just the blinking cursor. I switched to tty2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and then rerun the downloaded driver file from the tty2, though it is almost instantaneous and does not take much time. It gave me back GUI. But now I have to repeat the same process during each boot. How can I fix this so that I dont have to repeat on each boot?
Another thing that is not working is that this machine is not at all detecting external monitor. I tried both before and after nvidia driver installation. But its simply not working. How do I fix it?
PS
Some more observations:
$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for perception3: 
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:420-41f irq:209 memory:8c000000-8cffffff memory:4000000000-41ffffffff memory:4200000000-4201ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:520-51f iomemory:420-41f memory:5228000000-5228ffffff memory:4210000000-421fffffff memory:c0000-dffff memory:4202000000-4208ffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1200

Also, it says llvmpipe in graphics information:

Also, I am unable to change screen brightness.
Update 1
One more thing to add: I tried to determine ubuntu recommended driver as follows:
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000028B8sv0000103Csd00008CA3bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-545-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-545 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

In above output v535 seems to be recommended one. Also I tried following command as suggested by Hannu, to determine the driver:
$ ubuntu-drivers list 2>/dev/null | grep --color=none nvidia
nvidia-driver-545, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545)
nvidia-driver-535-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-545-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545-open)

Finally, I ended up installing first driver (v535 with suffix "tested") from additional drivers panel:

Above screenshot was taken before my current driver installation using *.run file. I had fresh Ubuntu installation and then installed from this Additional Drivers panel. It gave me just the blinking cursor after boot. No UI. I was not even able to switch to tty with Ctrl+Alt+Fn keys. So I reformatted, installed fresh ubuntu and then installed driver using *.run file.

ALWAYS use the prepackaged drivers in Ubuntu (they DO get updates occasionally!) rather than installing from the NVIDIA .run files - the Ubuntu packaged drivers are tested.

I tried ... it screwed up ubuntu ... booted to blinking cursor and I wasnt able to switch to GUI by any means. Thats why ended up using *.run.

Launchpad bug 2037004 indicates a db issue for the ubuntu-drivers (and Software&Updates/AdditionalDrivers) on 24.04, but I noticed even 22.04 pulled back on the 550 driver through ubuntu-drivers. The driver packages (standard repos and graphics-drivers PPA) are still available for a direct install: (sudo apt install nvidia-driver-555). I'm using 555 on a 3080,Ubuntu 24.04 without issues. Try using the latest one available on 22.04.

I'd recommend to remove the *.run -version
by executing it with an appended --uninstall (assuming it still is so);
These version(s) of the driver has been (at least) hard to retain in use while system parts get updated; apparently you have some kind of related problem by just rebooting.
Then reboot, and
list available drivers with:
$ ubuntu-drivers list 2>/dev/null | grep --color=none nvidia
... select one and install it with
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install ...
... or use the GUI; hit Super/Win-key and begin type, Additional drivers,
click on the (greenish) icon that appears, then select a driver from the presented list.
(Assuming you have [x] for 'Proprietary drivers for devices' in the leftmost tab of the same window)
Note: The very latest driver isn't always what you want, for stability reasons.
I'm currently using version 535.171.04 on my 1660Ti,
while there is a later version - which appeared glitchy for me, when I tried it
(just after installing 24.04).

Please check the update at the bottom of original post.

Just today there is a new version of the 535-driver at least for 24.04 (535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1). If it is available also for 22.04 I would try do this once more; you might get lucky.

Now, we have some progress. My collegue used to install software development related tools / libraries on his mahine, not with intention to fix this issue. But somehow, this issue seem to have fixed on his machine. I guess the tools that he installed must have modified some configs, but not sure which. Also he does not know exact which tool / library might have fixed this issue. So, now my question is can we somehow how find what configs fixed the issue on his machine and replicate it on others. If yes, what configs I should be looking for?

;-) well I for sure can only guess!  Look through the tools sudo apt-mark showmanual will tell which ones were manually installed. cd /var/cache/apt/archives/  and then ls -tr  -Fl --color=always --time-style=+" %F - %H.%M.%S " will show the downloaded .deb packages time sorted, latest last.

Resolved brightness and external monitor issue by adding acpi_backlight=intel to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" making it GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=intel" in /etc/default/grub, then running sudo update-grub and sudo reboot.

I resolved inability to connect external monitor and change brightness issues by performing following steps:

Edit file /etc/default/grub
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

(or whichever editor you are comformatble with ..)

Add acpi_backlight=intel
to line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" making it:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=intel"


Run
$ sudo update-grub


Reboot
$ sudo reboot



